# Builiding Dockerfile succeed on Mac M1, fails on Windows 10 WSL 2

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

containerizing an app that I did in the past, I started working on my Mac M1 and created the following Dockerfile (as you'll see, very very simple one):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY ../*.cs ./
COPY ../Properties ./

RUN dotnet publish -c Release

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0

COPY ./bin/Release/net6.0/publish app/
WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll"]
```

Launching the simplest

> docker build -t counter-image -f Dockerfile .

It works perfectly in MacM1, fails in Windows 10.
When I run docker build -t counter-image -f Dockerfile .

> #1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
> #1 sha256:a5c8a0c34c743f255ebdc15d65bfbbe5094a37db3462015427300b5d8afdb80e
> #1 transferring dockerfile: 403B done
> #1 DONE 0.1s
>
> #2 [internal] load .dockerignore
> #2 sha256:dc1169a26a22674179859bc7bb3820723365424bb8804c7917733b3b74ec5d65
> #2 transferring context: 2B done
> #2 DONE 0.1s
>
> #3 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0
> #3 sha256:0128d5218b10a50bf55970db7c113f09503205e2b2ada4931bb5d0c6628fdd2a
> #3 DONE 1.2s
>
> #5 [internal] load build context
> #5 sha256:0f49ce22f840bcf956513309e49cda3c26b83cb92b6e3f539b463beb14fb36e7
> #5 DONE 0.0s
>
> #4 [stage-1 1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0@sha256:dbf2ee47aeb7cc078d1351ef961913296d9044db8928b3d1cbb88d7d3e87cccb
> #4 sha256:2aacc73d23873adb384695e176a97f35524a7a10087c170e336161af3a1b4ce3
> #4 resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0@sha256:dbf2ee47aeb7cc078d1351ef961913296d9044db8928b3d1cbb88d7d3e87cccb
> 0.1s done
> #4 sha256:dbf2ee47aeb7cc078d1351ef961913296d9044db8928b3d1cbb88d7d3e87cccb
> 2.17kB / 2.17kB done
> #4 sha256:b534d6bba13c1654a13497dfcb04ad0b398772b5d1da0e5bec5e0a3e38e15ccb
> 1.16kB / 1.16kB done
> #4 sha256:8b872fde0fc7d2e58dd4f04ad53f21d27043640978dd7730add604f9b58ed207
> 2.80kB / 2.80kB done
> #4 CANCELED
>
> #5 [internal] load build context
> #5 sha256:0f49ce22f840bcf956513309e49cda3c26b83cb92b6e3f539b463beb14fb36e7
> #5 transferring context: 25B done
> #5 DONE 0.1s
>
> ### #6 [stage-1 2/3] COPY ./bin/Release/net6.0/publish MindsphereConfigurationMover/
> #6 sha256:434ed7ed1150d04fac20d05feeb2d63aa5bdcf9cf63821709aa8091d48422119
> #6 ERROR: "/bin/Release/net6.0/publish" not found: not found
>
> > [stage-1 2/3] COPY ./bin/Release/net6.0/publish MindsphereConfigurationMover/:
> > ------ failed to compute cache key: "/bin/Release/net6.0/publish" not found: not found

It looks like it cannot get the sdk/runtime so the following publish fails, but it makes little sense to me.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're expecting the `COPY ./bin/Release/net6.0/publish app/` line to copy the published app from the project that was built earlier on in the Dockerfile. But that's not what it's actually doing. It's attempting to copy from the `bin/Release/net6.0/publish` of your local file system (your build context location), outside of the container. So, likely, this directory exists on your M1 Mac but not your Windows machine.

The reason it's attempting to copy from the local file system is because you've not indicated in the `COPY` instruction that it should copy from a Dockerfile stage. This can be done with the following syntax: `COPY --from=<stage-name> <source-path> <destination-path>`. In order to reference a stage name, you need to declare the stage name as well which also hasn't been done in this Dockerfile. The stage you would want to reference is that the one using the `sdk` image.

Here's the suggested Dockerfile to use:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY ../*.cs ./
COPY ../Properties ./

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll"]
```

You can see .NET Dockerfiles that demonstrate this pattern at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/tree/main/samples.